Who contributed [GT13] to "Computers and Intractability"?
This is a followup to my question How does the complexity of calculating the Permanent imply the NP completeness of directed 3-cycle cover?
Question:

who contributed problem [GT13] PARTITION INTO HAMILTON SUBGRAPHS to Garey and Johnson's Computers and Intractability?

The mystery about [GT13] is for one thing that it isn't explicitly mentioned or proved in the cited publications of Valiant or Herrmann and, for another thing that Bläser and Manthey first cited Valiant as the reference for an NP-completeness proof, but in their later paper "Computing cycle covers without short cycles" provided a proof for the NP-completeness of [GT13] but Valiant is not mentioned anymore and also doesn't appear in their citations list.
Update:
I just found the (paywalled) article by Bermond: Hamiltonian Decompositions of Graphs, Directed Graphs and Hypergraphs.
From the publication date 1978 and subject it seems a closer match for the origin of [GT13] than Valiant's paper that introduced the #P complexity class.
Update II:
a further likely candidate publication is the 1978 paper Some Matching Problems for Bipartite Graphs which proves the NP Completeness of bipartite matching with cardinality constraints; as directed cycle covers are the solution to biadjacency matching, that paper may come close as well.

What is the article by Bläser and Manthey you mentioned?  Semantic Scholar thinks that they have a paper whose title, "Computing cycle covers without short cycles", is close to the one you mention, but that paper seems actually to be by Bläser and Siebert.

@LSpice Siebert is the birthname of Bodo Manthey; he is also the author of some subsequent papers that are related to the topic of calculating cycle covers with bounds on cycle lengths.

Re, OK, thanks. So the paper you are citing is Computing cycle covers without short cycles?

@LSpice that is the case

I think this question belongs on [hsm.se] rather than here. The original linked one is a mathematical question, but this one seems a history one to me.

here is a link to solving  GT[13] on a quantum computer
